# Count in fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fields-for

I've a list of triplocations in a Trip which i would like to edit. The triplocations are associated with my Trip(Alot of locations in a trip). In my edit form I would like to number every location from 1 to * for the user to see. I know there's an option called each_with_index. But that doesn't apply to me because i need to use fields_for.

I've seen a solution on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index) but if i use that each_with_index on my @trip i will only count to 1(Only 1 trip in my trips edit obviously). And if i use @trip.triplocations in that each and the fields_for in it, i get 3 times the same output(There are 3 locations present) and that's not what i want either.

What i actually want is:

1
title :value of DB
description :value of DB

2
title :value of DB
description :value of DB

The form works like a charm as it does with just the fields_for. But i just miss a count above every form. Could anyone help me out here?

Here's my trips' edit form:

```
<%= form_for(@trip) do |f| %>
    <br> <br>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <br> <br>
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
    <br> <br>
    <%= f.fields_for :triplocations do |a| %>
        <p class="locations">
            <%= a.label :title, 'Titel:' %>
            <%= a.text_field :title, :id => 'titleField' %>

            <%= a.label :description, 'Omschrijving:' %>
            <%= a.text_field :description , :id => 'descriptionField'%>

            <%= a.hidden_field  :latlng, :id => 'latlngField' %>
        </p> 
        <div id="inputFields"></div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit :value => "Route opslaan" %>
<% end %>
```

Edit: I fixed it now by the basic i = 1 and at the end of the fields_for loop i = i+1. But i'm sure someone else can come up with a better way, right?