# HABTM checkbox in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I am trying to implement a HABTM checkbox in a nested form.

Currently, I have 3 models. Subject, lesson and groups.
The associations are as follows:
Each subject has many lessons.
Each lesson has and belongs to many groups.

Right now, I am trying to implement them all on a single creation and edit form.
Such that a lesson is nested in the subject and for each lesson there is a list of group check boxes to implement the HABTM relationship.

I am facing trouble implementing the HABTM relationship as there are many lessons per subjects and I am not sure how I could distinguish between the different lessons.

To elaborate further, I am able to get the nested form working but I can't get the HABTM checkboxes to save to the right lessons.
The following code sample is my HABTM checkbox implementation.

```
  <% Group.all.each do |group|%>
      <%= check_box_tag "subject[lessons_attributes[0]][group_ids][]", group.id, f.object.groups.include?(group) %>
      <%= group.group_index %>
  <%end%>
```

Currently, I have saved it to the first lesson using this line "subject[lessons_attributes[0]][group_ids][]".

However, the number of lessons vary and I am not too sure how I could determine the lesson "number", i.e. the bolded 0 in "subject[lessons_attributes[**0**]][group_ids][]". Such that I could save the groups to the correct lesson.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: just to clarify, you want a separate list of checkboxes for each lesson right?

Comment: yea, but the lesson is nested in the subject and I am not sure how I could get the number which it would be sent at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the best practice is to prebuild (a few) lesson object on the subject (that is the form.object), then you iterate over them to have per-lesson fields. 
if you use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) or [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), collection select via checkboxes is easy:

```
<% form_for @subject do |form| %>
  ....
  <% form.fields_for :lessons do |lesson_form| %>
    ...
    <% lesson_form.input :group_ids, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

if you wanna use `check_box_tag`, you should iterate through lessons with an index and substitute the index in your checkbox name:

```
<% form_for @subject do |form| %>
  ....
  <% @subject.lessons.each_with_index do |l, i| %>
     <% Group.all.each do |group|%>
        <%= check_box_tag "subject[lessons_attributes[#{i}]][group_ids][]", group.id, l.groups.include?(group) %>
        <%= group.group_index %>
     <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, let me try it out.

Comment: Got it working with the second method and with reference to this question on implementing rails fields for with index. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index. I would perhaps look into using simple form in the future. Thanks once again!

Comment: Why the `[]` at the end of the check box name?

Comment: The [] notation indicates to the browser and rails that multiple HTTP parameters of the same name but distinct values are to be submitted with the form. The array notation indicates that an array of values will be associated with the same name.

Answer (score 9):

**For those working with Rails 4 and having the same question (as I had)**

The `Group.all.each` loop in [@Viktor Trón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641672/viktor-tron)'s answer is unnecessary:
There's a new FormBuilder method, [collection_check_boxes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes), which has been created just for that!

Your code would be:

```
<% form_for @subject do |form| %>
  ....
  <% @subject.lessons.each_with_index do |l, i| %>
     <%= form.fields_for :lessons, l do |lesson_fields|%>
        <%= lesson_fields.collection_check_boxes :group_ids, Group.all, :id, :group_index %>
     <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You then have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :lessons` to your `Subject` model, and in your `SubjectsController`, change the `subject_params` method to "permit" nested params for lessons:

```
params.require(:subject).permit(..., lessons_attributes: [:id, group_ids: []])
```

In your `SubjectsController`, the `create` or `update` actions remain unchanged: `@subject = Subject.create(subject_params)` for instance, will create the Subject, the associated lessons and update their HABTM relationships to groups correctly (unless I made a mistake somewhere!).