# Rails 4 : Nested forms HABTM checkboxes problems, Child Object doesnt get -entirly- saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to create an **Ice Cream** object/s while creating an **Order** object using the same form, I have followed **Rails casts** tutorial on this subject, Viewed many other questions and answers, And nothing seems to work. I can create the **Order** and I manged to got the **Ice Cream** object to be saved Thanks to `Pavan`'s answer BUT NOT ENTIRLY. Seems I've problems with my check boxes **Flavors** & **Extras**   , Please help. **Here's my code...**

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :shift
    has_many :ice_creams
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ice_creams
end
```

ice_craem.rb

```
class IceCream < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :size
    belongs_to :basis
    has_and_belongs_to_many :flavors
    belongs_to :sauce
    belongs_to :topping
    has_many :added_extras
    has_many :extras, :through => :added_extras
    belongs_to :order
end
```

orders_controller.rb

```
 class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.ice_creams.build
    @ice_cream = IceCream.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:shift_id, :user_id, :discount, :total, :total_after_discount, :paid, :remaining, ice_creams_attributes: [:size_id, :basis_id, :sauce_id, :topping_id, :extra_one_id, :extra_two_id, :extra_three_id, :extra_four_id, :extra_five_id, :ice_cream_price, :extras_price, :total_price, :flavor_ids => [], :extra_ids => []])
    end
end
```

New order form: _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :shift_id, value: get_shift %>

  <%= f.fields_for :ice_creams do |builder| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :size_id %><br>
      <%= builder.collection_select :size_id, Size.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, {class: ""} %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :basis_id %><br>
      <%= builder.collection_select :basis_id, Basis.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, {class: ""} %>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <%= hidden_field_tag "ice_cream[flavor_ids][]", nil %>
      <% Flavor.all.each do |flavor| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "ice_cream[flavor_ids][]", flavor.id, @ice_cream.flavor_ids.include?(flavor.id), class: 'flvs' %>
        <%= flavor.name %> <br>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :sauce_id %><br>
      <%= builder.collection_select :sauce_id, Sauce.all,:id,:name, {prompt: true}, {class: ""} %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :topping_id %><br>
      <%= builder.collection_select :topping_id, Topping.all,:id,:name, {prompt: true}, {class: ""} %>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <%= hidden_field_tag "ice_cream[extra_ids][]", nil %>
      <% Extra.all.each do |extra| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "ice_cream[extra_ids][]", extra.id, @ice_cream.extra_ids.include?(extra.id) %>
        <%= extra.name %> <br>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :ice_cream_price %><br>
      <%= builder.text_field :ice_cream_price %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :extras_price %><br>
      <%= builder.text_field :extras_price %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :total_price %><br>
      <%= builder.text_field :total_price %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :discount %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :discount %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :total %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :total %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :total_after_discount %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :total_after_discount %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :paid %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :paid %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :remaining %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :remaining %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you

Comment: The new method has     @order.ice_creams.build  when it should be what you use to create and save the object in your create method!

Comment: @bkunzi01 I've tried to put what I use to create a new Ice Cream but i kept give me an error, Also I've never seen in any tutorial that method having more code than that. It supoused to be very simple job to make nested form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manneged to find the answer myself... Here's the updated code.

orders_controller.rb from :

```
  ...
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.ice_creams.build
    @ice_cream = IceCream.new
  end
  ...
```

To :

```
  ...
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.ice_creams.build
  end
  ...
```

New order form: _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :ice_creams do |builder| %>
     ...
    <div class="">
      <%= builder.label :flavor_ids %><br>
      <%= builder.collection_check_boxes :flavor_ids, Flavor.all, :id, :name %>
      ... 
    <div class="">
      <%= builder.label :extra_ids %><br>
      <%= builder.collection_check_boxes :extra_ids, Extra.all, :id, :name %>
      ...
  <% end %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

I found a rails form helper that creates collection of check boxes called `collection_check_boxes` works the same way of `collection_select` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21852624/5306391), That some how It did all the heavy lifting for me and the checked checkboxes kept checked in the update form.

Also many thanks to @Pavan and his answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `<%= fields_for :ice_creams do |builder| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :ice_creams do |builder| %>` so that the right `params` will get passed to the *controller* and child object is created.

***Update:***

The problem with the check boxes is also the same. They should be changed to below

```
<% Flavor.all.each do |flavor| %>
  <%= builder.check_box :flavor_ids, flavor.id, @ice_cream.flavor_ids.include?(flavor.id), class: 'flvs' %>
  <%= flavor.name %> <br>
<% end %>

<% Extra.all.each do |extra| %>
  <%= builder.check_box :extra_ids, extra.id, @ice_cream.extra_ids.include?(extra.id) %>
  <%= extra.name %> <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, It's finally began to work. But I've had to add @ice_cream = IceCream.new to orders_controller new method to avoid some error on the check boxes fields. I can now create and save the ice cream object but without the parameters in the check boxes like flavors and extras.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I managed to get it fixed more relevant.