# How to get index in partial with fields_for on nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Given:

```
<%= f.fields_for :socials do |builder| %>
  <%= render :partial => "social_fields", :locals => { :f => builder} %>
<% end %>
```

how can I get a counter/index inside the _social_fields.html.erb counter (in order to to something on the last item)?  social_fields_counter seems to only be generated if you explicitly pass :collection to render, but these are nested objects with accepts_nested_attributes_for :socials in the parent.

Comment: I believe the answer to [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index) question is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

Inside `_social_fields.html.erb`:

```
<%= f.options[:child_index] %>
```

Comment: So simple and perfect!

Comment: Odd, I get `nil` from that

Comment: @valery  This is working fine it gives values in this way : '1450681048049,1450681050158,1450681056830,1450681141951,1450681219262'. But I need index in this form '1,2,3,4,5'. What should I do?

Comment: @vidal it look like object_ids but has to be indexes 0,1,2,3,4