# Fields_for with nested attribute, has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

I have 3 models - **standards**, **layers**, and **layers_assocs**. Standards has many layers through layer_assocs and the rest is trivial. The **layers_assocs** table stores the `standards_id`, `layer_id` and a `visible` boolean while the **layers** table is just a look up table with `name` (and auto-increment `id`).

On the standards options page, I have a check box which updates the `:visible` nested attribute. I'm looking for a way to show the associated layer name in a form label. Currently, I have this for the check box:

```
<%= f.fields_for :layers_assocs do |assoc| %>
  <%= assoc.check_box :visible %>
<% end %>
```

How I would display the associated layer name with the **layers_assocs** `belongs_to` **layers** association is a mystery. I can display `layer_id` with this

```
<%= assoc.text_field :layer_id %>
```

But trying to use that as an integer for displaying name through layers like `standard.layers[assoc.layer_id]` or `standard.layers[:layer_id]` doesn't fly. `assoc` is a FormBuilder object so I'm not sure what to do. Inspecting `assoc` spits out a *huge* object with everything in the standard.

I've checked the [rails api on `fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index) with no luck. Either `:name` or `:visible` is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it. Must have been the coffee.

```
<% @standard.layers_assocs.each do |assoc| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :layers_assocs, assoc do |layer_field| %>
    <%= layer_field.label assoc.layer.name %>
    <%= layer_field.check_box :visible %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For the check box to work, it needs the visible attribute as a key. `f.check_box layer_assoc.visible` will just think you're trying to force feed it 'true' or 'false'. The issue with getting the name then is that when `:visible` is in the right scope, `layer_assoc.layer.name` isn't accessible within the `fields_for` block because `layer_field` is a FormBuilder object, not a `layers_assoc` object. The above makes sure both scopes are available and the output isn't overdone. `f.fields_for :layers_assoc` would output as many duplicates as there are objects in the standards `layer_assocs` array. `f.fields_for :layers_assoc, assoc` limits it to the correct amount.

Note that the form label isn't properly "attached" with `for="..."` in the output HTML to it's associated check box. I can deal with it but let me know if you know a better way.