# RoR - access individually after building x.times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build

On the controller I have

```
def new
 @addendum = @contract.addendums.build
    2.times do
      @addendum.locations.build
    end
end
```

How can I access individually to each `location` on the `view form`. for instance, how can I make a title like **First Location** and **Second Location** before the first and the second location built? in the view form I use
`<% addendum.fields_for :locations do |local|%>
  <%= local.label :value%><%= local.number_field :value%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Nuno, I read your question wrong the first time so I deleted my first answer and started over.

I think this previous question should work for you:  [Rails: fields_for with index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index)