# has_many field_for and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, fields-for

I am tryng to learning nested attributes with a simple app.

```
 class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :avatars
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatars

 end

 class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ticket
 end

 <%= form_for @ticket do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %> 
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

  <%= f.fields_for :avatar**s** do |m| %>
    <%= m.label :name %>
    <%= m.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Using :avatars(plural) the fields doesn't display instead it works with:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :avatar do |m| %>
```

What I'am missing?

Edit

Thank you all.

I find the problem: on ticket controller

```
      def new
       @ticket = Ticket.new
       @ticket.avatars.build #before this line is missing
      end
```

Now i don't know how to show in the view this nested value

```
     @ticket.comments.name
```

give me undefined method 'name' on avatars controllers

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are creating one avatar at the time, since you have to use singular.

If you want to iterate through multiple avatars, you will have to use foreach, `<% @ticket.avatars.each do %>`.

Also, take a look at:
http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/

Comment: That is actually not true. `forms_for` renders its body for all associated objects.

Comment: Are you sure? How does rails know how many instances of avatar( in this particular example) will create? I am open to any other suggestion why this doesn't work

Comment: I am dead sure! The problem here is that we don't know where `@ticket` comes from. If it already has a number of associated `avatars` they will all get rendered. You can even [get the index of item being rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index).

Comment: Yeah, I kinda assummed that user will add number of avatars as he wish (no predefined number of avatars)

Comment: I see your point. Nevertheless I think when `forms_for` takes care of all associations, why write a loop?

Comment: I had problems with that approach on adding additional fields, and found that this was correct solution.

Comment: Good to hear that. Since I don't know what the problem was I cannot comment any further.