# uninitialized constant error when using Ruby Object in lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, object, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app with a fairly complicated form that uses Ruby Objects in the lib folder (my first time with ruby objects).  I keep getting an uninitialized constant error like this: 
[Add Multiple Nested Attributes through checkboxes Rails 4 (maybe with multiple forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929153/add-multiple-nested-attributes-through-checkboxes-rails-4-maybe-with-multiple-f)

```
uninitialized constant ProjectsController::ProjectUpdater
```

What my form is trying to do is create starter tasks & starter milestones based on premade "template" tasks and milestones. So when a user creates a Project, they have some common tasks already added.  This code relates directly to this previous question & answer:

my controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

def new_milestones
    @project.milestones.build
    @project.tasks.build
    @milestones_templates = MilestoneTemplate.where(template_id: @project.template_id)
  end

 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      **result = ProjectUpdater.perform(@project, update_params) == true** <-- the error is on this line
      if result == true
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        @project = result
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:id, :name, :template_id, milestone_attributes:[{:names => []},  {:ids => []}, { :milestone_ids => []},:id, :name, :project_id, :milestone_template_id, :project_id, task_attributes: [{:names => []},  {:ids => []}, { :task_ids => []}, :id, :name, :milestone_id, :task_template_id, :project_id, :_destroy]])
    end
  end
```

lib/project_updater.rb

```
class ProjectUpdater

  def self.perform(project, params)
    milestones = params[:project][:milestones]
    #Create and save each milestone
    # You might be able to us nested attributes to save tasks.

    if project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      return true
    else
      return project
    end
  end
end
```

my form

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <% @milestones_templates.each_with_index do |milestone, index| %>
    <br>
    <%= f.fields_for :milestones, index: index do |fm| %>
      <%= fm.hidden_field :name, value: milestone.name %>
      <!-- Create a checkbox to add the milestone_id to the project -->
      <%= fm.label milestone.name %>
      <%= fm.check_box :milestone_template_id,{}, milestone.id %>
      <br>
      <% milestone.task_templates.each_with_index do |task, another_index| %>
        <%= fm.fields_for :tasks, index: another_index do |ft| %>
          <!-- Create a checkbox for each task in the milestone -->
          <%= ft.label task.name %>
          <%= ft.check_box :task_ids, {}, task.id %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <br>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <br>
<%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: In this code there is `ProjectUpdater`, which is defined in /lib. However, somewhere these is a call to  `ProjectMilestoneBuilder` in your projects controller. Find and replace with `ProjectUpdater`

Comment: sorry,  I had two windows open with the two versions you gave me.  The correct error can't find ProjectUpdater, not ProjectMilestoneBuilder(older code you provided). I've corrected my question. This error is from a pure pull of the code you provided.  Sorry about the confusion.  5am my time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to require the ruby files in the `/lib` directory and make sure you follow the naming convention.. like

```
        # in lib/foo.rb:
        class Foo
        end

        # in lib/foo/bar.rb:
        class Foo::Bar
        end

    # in you case, in lib/project_updater.rb
    class ProjectUpdater
      def self.perform (your_params,,,)
        # your code
      end
    end
```

in config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths << %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

This may help you, prehaps :)

Comment: I am very new to this....so I put the class ProjectUpdater  twice? once in the lib/ProjectUpdater.rb and once in lib/ProjectUpdater/ProjectUpdater.rb?  The same file?

Comment: If you were to put the `ProjectUpdater` in directly in the lib folder, then it would be as the first example. However, if you put `ProjectUpdater` in `/lib/something` then you have to put the `Something` module around it. In this confusing case `foo`

Comment: you can remove `lib/ProjectUpdater/ProjectUpdater.rb` and rename the file `lib/ProjectUpdater.rb` to `lib/project_updater.rb`

Comment: As for the answer, I'd recommend that you change the file name to be the same in both cases, ie. `class Bar::Foo` and also make the naming more explicit and easier to understand by removing the shorthand `::` and using a module call

    `module Bar
       class Foo
       end
    end`

Comment: @Cba Bhusal I've asked another related question.  The adding config.autoload_paths fixed it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131850/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-ruby-object-in-lib-rails

Comment: @xcskier56 I have asked a related question, if you have the time:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131850/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-ruby-object-in-lib-rails