# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass Ruby Object in lib Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, object, nested-attributes

I have an app with a fairly complicated form that uses Ruby Objects in the lib folder (my first time with ruby objects).  I can't figure out how to create the multiple :task_ids in my Update Nested Attributes form, even though the params are defined in my Ruby Object Custom Class (this is my first time using this and I am learning how to call it).  I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What my form is trying to do is create starter tasks & starter milestones based on premade "template" tasks and milestones. So when a user creates a Project, they have some common tasks already added.  This code relates directly to this previous question & answer:
[Add Multiple Nested Attributes through checkboxes Rails 4 (maybe with multiple forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929153/add-multiple-nested-attributes-through-checkboxes-rails-4-maybe-with-multiple-f/29018896#29018896)

my controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

def new_milestones
    @project.milestones.build
    @project.tasks.build
    @milestones_templates = MilestoneTemplate.where(template_id: @project.template_id)
  end

 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      result = ProjectUpdater.perform(@project, update_params) == true
      if result == true
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        @project = result
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:id, :name, :template_id, milestone_attributes:[{:names => []},  {:ids => []}, { :milestone_ids => []},:id, :name, :project_id, :milestone_template_id, :project_id, task_attributes: [{:names => []},  {:ids => []}, { :task_ids => []}, :id, :name, :milestone_id, :task_template_id, :project_id, :_destroy]])
    end
  end
```

lib/project_updater.rb

```
class ProjectUpdater

  def self.perform(project, params)
    **milestones = params[:project][:milestones]** <--- this is the line where the error is
    #Create and save each milestone
    # You might be able to us nested attributes to save tasks.

    if project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      return true
    else
      return project
    end
  end
end
```

my form

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <% @milestones_templates.each_with_index do |milestone, index| %>
    <br>
    <%= f.fields_for :milestones, index: index do |fm| %>
      <%= fm.hidden_field :name, value: milestone.name %>
      <!-- Create a checkbox to add the milestone_id to the project -->
      <%= fm.label milestone.name %>
      <%= fm.check_box :milestone_template_id,{}, milestone.id %>
      <br>
      <% milestone.task_templates.each_with_index do |task, another_index| %>
        <%= fm.fields_for :tasks, index: another_index do |ft| %>
          <!-- Create a checkbox for each task in the milestone -->
          <%= ft.label task.name %>
          <%= ft.check_box :task_ids, {}, task.id %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <br>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <br>
<%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

what is being submitted:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"do/NeMW4wvsh8PCOIYAvuDiH0DwKVr6v0Sm55gOuCHM/Fw5h9T0orRjrspcQpNSx5Vp2JOmtVf+3O18P2XB4vA==", "project"=>{"milestones"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Yellow Milestone 1", "milestone_template_id"=>"18", "tasks"=>{"0"=>{"task_ids"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"task_ids"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"task_ids"=>"0"}}}, "1"=>{"name"=>"Yellow Milestone 2", "milestone_template_id"=>"0", "tasks"=>{"0"=>{"task_ids"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"task_ids"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"task_ids"=>"0"}}}, "2"=>{"name"=>"Yellow Milestone 3", "milestone_template_id"=>"0", "tasks"=>{"0"=>{"task_ids"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"task_ids"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"task_ids"=>"0"}}}}}, "commit"=>"Update Project", "controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"155"}
```

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)


module Taskit


    class Application < Rails::Application

        config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
        config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
      end


    end
```

Comment: Didn't the error message come with a source file name and a line number? They usually do...

Comment: Yes, I've marked it in the code above with an arrow and a note. It's under Self.perform in lib/project_updater.rb

Comment: Is there an association relationship between the `project` model and the `milestone_template`? At the risk of stating the obvious, `params[:project]` is `nil`, so the `milestone` information isn't being passed back as a nested attribute.

Comment: no.  project has_many milestones, and milestone_template has_many task_templates.  project is not related to milestone_template, except that it is a child of template which has_many milestone_templates.....basically you create a project and you are given milestone_templates that autocreate milestones for your project.

Comment: Does your `project` model have an `accepts_nested_attributes_for :milestones`?

Comment: it would have been great and easy to answer if you have posted bunch of lines from server log with errors along with the question my friend :)

Comment: @lurker yes, project accepts nested_attributes for :milestones and :tasks

Comment: @CbaBhusal thank you for the tip.  The server log is what the terminal prints out, correct? I am new.

Comment: How can I formulate my question so it does not get  voted down? I don't understand.

Comment: yes @NothingToSeeHere, just copy and paste the server log (terminal print outs) in formatted way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think there is a typo in this line:

```
result = ProjectUpdater.perform(@project, update_params)
```

I don't see an `update_params` method, so I think this should be `project_params` instead.

The problem in ProjectUpdater is because `params.require(:project)` returns a hash without the outer :project key, so in the `ProjectUpdater.perform` method get rid of the :project key:

```
milestones = params[:milestones]
```

Comment: Ah,  I did have to add params to ProjectUpdater.perform(@project, project_params, params) to get milestones= params[:milestones] to work...but it did!