# Update multiple records in nested model from checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been struggling with this for quite a few days and I have read half a dozen SO answers but can't seem to find the right way to achieve what I need. The latest one I looked at is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929153/add-multiple-nested-attributes-through-checkboxes-rails-4-maybe-with-multiple-f). I couldn't work out how to adapt this to my needs.

I have been marked down before for not asking a question correctly so I have tried to include as much detail in my question as possible. If this is too much please don't mark the question down just suggest changes and I will oblige.

Basically I want to update multiple records, at once, in a nested model, from checkboxes in a nested form.

I have 2 models, the first is a Message model:-

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_recipients, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :message_recipients, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The second is a MessageRecipient model:-

```
class MessageRecipient < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :message, optional: true
end
```

In my Messages controller I have 2 methods:-

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
  4.times do
   @message.message_recipients.build
  end
end

def create
 @message = Message.new(message_params)
 respond_to do |format|
   if @message.save
     format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
   end
```

I also have this for allowing params in the controller:-

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:user_id, :expirydate, :subject, :messagebody, :createdate, {message_recipients_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :role]} )
end
```

In my view I have:-

```
<%= form_with(model: message, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :messagebody %>
    <%= form.text_field :messagebody %>
  </div>
    <%= form.fields_for :message_recipients do |m| %>
      <%= m.select :role, options_for_select(User.role_for_messages.map {|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, v]}, :selected => m.object.role)  %>
   <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now all of this works perfectly well and does exactly what I need, however rather than using multiple selects I want to convert this to use checkboxes. To do this I have changed my view file to have:-

```
<%= form.fields_for :message_recipients do |m| %>
  <%= m.collection_check_boxes :role, User.role_for_messages, :second, :first do |b| %>
      <div class="collection-check-box"> %>
         <%= b.check_box %>
         <%= b.label %>
      </div> %>
    <% end %> 
   <% end %>
```

I have also changed message_params to allow the checkbox array in:-

```
params.require(:message).permit(:user_id, :expirydate, :subject, :messagebody, :createdate, {message_recipients_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :role =>[]] } )
```

And finally I have changed the messages controller New method to:-

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
  @message.message_recipients.build
end
```

The problem is whilst I am getting no console errors I am also not getting multiple child records created. I actually get one record created but without any of the values from the checkbox. I think it is something to do with how the params are being generated but I just can't work out what the issue is. For completeness I have included the params generated below:-

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qKQ+Ove7DRJqUIZ+NlgCdM85G9Mf5p8h1gWCF36vd9ODa40G4miKkhHaNbG7grpVFqqCiF7uq+BT8G9Olvm5qQ==", "message"=>{"user_id"=>"3", "subject"=>"Subject 3", "messagebody"=>"Message Body 3", "createdate"=>"2018-12-21", "expirydate"=>"09/08/18", "message_recipients_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"role"=>["", "0", "1", "2", "3"]}}}, "commit"=>"Create Message"}
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction and/or provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this working now with the following code in the 'create' method. Just in case this helps anyone else out trying to achive the same thing. Feel free to comment if this is not considered good practice.

```
 def create
  # create the message and save it so I can access it's ID
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  @message.save

  # populate a new array with the role attributes and discard any that are empty
  params_array = params[:message_recipients_attributes][:role]
  params_array.reject!(&:empty?)

  #loop through the roles and create new child records with the message_id and role(s)
  params_array.each  do |doo|
    @message_recipients = MessageRecipient.new(:message_id => @message.id, :role => doo)
    @message_recipients.save
  end

  #standard boilerplate for checking the message saved and redirecting user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.save
      format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```