# How to write into the counter into a database with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, count, nested

I'm trying to write into a scaffold the opening hours of businesses.

I'm doing this, using nested database, in particular I'm following this tutorial

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?

adapting it to my case. The tutorial shows survey creation, whereas I'm recording opening business hours.

Everything is working as it should but I have a problem counting days..

I'm using this in my controller:

```
def new
    @biz = Biz.new
    7.times { @biz.hours.build }

  end
```

In this way I'm writing 7 times the business hours in my module and it is working properly. 
My problem is with the "day_id" that I want to POST in my database, ideally it should be 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday etc.. but my Input view is set in this way:

```
<%= f.fields_for :hours do |builder| %> 
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> <%= builder.label :day, "Monday" %> <%= builder.text_field 
:day, :value => "1", :style =>"display: none" %> </td>
        <td> <%= builder.time_select :open_time %> </td>
        <td> <%= builder.time_select :close_time %> </td>
        <td> <%= builder.check_box :chiusurastra %> </td>
        <td> <%= builder.text_field :motivochistra %> </td>
    </tbody>
  <% end %>
```

Of course this isn't working because the "day" is always getting 1 each of the 7 times that the controller runs (and also I'm displaying always Monday in the view)

Is there a way to change accordingly to the controller execution the :value => "1" that I've used in the view and the "Monday" that I'm displaying each of the 7 time?

[The input view that I'm showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcjAr.png)

Many thanks!

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index#17778589

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 7.times in your controller you could do

`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].each do |day|
  @biz.hours.build :day => day
end`

In order to display the day names in the label you can work with an array too.

```
day_names = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

The tricky part here is to get the array index matching to your day number. If at some point you want to work with localization files such as, https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml the week starts with Sunday (day_names[0]) and ends with Saturday (day_names[6]). So I recommend changing your day indexes to [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] and start with 0 = Sunday

In your view you can change the day column to something like this:

```
<td><%= builder.label :day, day_names[day] %> <%= builder.hidden_field :day %></td>
```

the value of the hidden field should be set automatically

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works great but I don't know where to declare the array. If I write it in the controller as you did and call it in the view, I get this error: 
    NameError in Bizs#new
    Showing c:/sites/bizzo/app/views/bizs/_form.html.erb where line #66 raised:

    undefined local variable or method `day_names' for #<# 
   <Class:0x000000000da194f8>:0x000000000e935680>

Comment: I solved it declaring the array in the model. In the view if I write this <%= ApplicationRecord::DAY_NAMES[0] %> it shows me "Sunday", so the declaration went fine. However when I substitute the [0] with [day] (<%= builder.label :day, ApplicationRecord::DAY_NAMES[day] %>), I got this error: undefined local variable or method `day' for #<#<Class:0x00000000092fab30>:0x000000000e651478>. I can't figure it out!!

Comment: For a start you could just put the day_names array in your view, so that you are sure you can access it. Regarding the day local variable you need to see if it's actually passed into the view. Use your browser's Inspect tool to see if the hidden field actually has a value or if it is blank. And is your attribute called day or day_id into which you want to write the number?