# How to dynamically increment a counter inside fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for

I am building a form where someone can add daily challenges through a form. This form should list the items for each day of the week vertically. These days should be grouped by week #.

In this manner:

Week 1

- Challenge #1
- Challenge #2
- Challenge #3

Week 2

- Challenge #4
- Challenge #5
- Challenge #6

I use a button to add items dynamically and the incrementing should happen when these items are added too. After 7 daily challenges within a week, a new week section should be created on the UI.

I've used fields_for and tried using a simple counter, incrementing it within each iteration.

```rb
<% i = 1 %>

<div id="challenges_container">
<%= f.fields_for :challenges do |mi| %>
<% i += 1 %>
<%= i %>

<% end %>
</div>

<p><%= f.link_to_add '<i class="fi-plus"></i> Add Challenge'.html_safe, :challenges, :data => {:target => '#challenges_container'} %></p>
```

I expected the 'i' counter to be incrementing by one every time I click on the 'Add Challenge' button but it only gets set to '2' when I load the page initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at: [Rails: fields_for with index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index)

In your case, try:

```
<% @challenges.each_with_index do |challenge, index| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :challenges, challenge do |fc| %>
  ## Do whatever you want with challenge and index
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that Mark has pointed out does work fine to get the indexes of items at first load. For anyone looking into making it work dynamically, I had to use Javascript. You can find more info about it here: [Javascript events](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#javascript-events) That way you can manipulate the DOM even after it's loaded (for adding new elements, for example).